# Request in Controller after submitting a form in ASPX using MVC3 action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchPage() {

         return View();
      }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search( string option, string text ) {
    // how to get request values-> and then I don't need the above parameters

    ViewData["Results"] = _some.Search(option, text); //option and text should be from Request
         return RedirectToAction( "SearchPage" );
}
```

and the SearchPage code:

```
<form action="<%=Url.Action("Search","Persons")%>" method="post" name="search-form">

<select name="search-option" id="search-option">
<option value="category">Category</option>
<option value="discipline">Discipline</option>
<option value="manufacturer">Manufacturer</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />

</form>

<% if ( ViewData["Results"] != null ) {
      %>
         <p>Test</p>
      <%
   }
%>
```

How to get the values submitted (the value from selectbox and the text from input text) with HttpRequest class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should have something like

```
`<select name="searchOption" id="searchOption">`
```

and

```
`public ActionResult Search( string searchOption, string keyword) {`
```

You can't use the character "-" in your view's parameters because you can't translate that in an automatically mapped parameter for your action.

That being said, if you don't want to use action parameters for this one you can use something like:

```
`Request.Params["search-option"]`
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways.

Make your method take a FormCollection parameter:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var key = formCollection["key"];
```

Or use the default model binder and have parameters for every field you want:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(string name)
```

Or

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(Person person)
```

and in your view

```
<input name="Person.name" />
```

Or create your own model binder.

If you want you can access the request but if you want to go that route - use FormCollection.

Answer (score 1):

With asp.net-mvc, you do not need to manually extract values from `HttpRequest`. Framework does this automatically, and its called model binding. In case of ints, strings, and other simple type parameters, just `name` html inputs with same names as their parameters on action method, that's all. Naming is a tiny bit different for nested propertis and lists.

```
<select name="option" id="option">
<option value="category">Category</option>
<option value="discipline">Discipline</option>
<option value="manufacturer">Manufacturer</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="text" id="keyword" />
```

Now, in action, option and text will have values.